# async/await con map retorna promesas pendientes

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

quería pedir ayuda con un tema que no estoy pudiendo resolver. Estoy queriendo consultar la api de star wars (swapi) y quiero armar un objeto con los personajes y sus atributos. El tema está que algunas atributos están disponibles como propiedades del objeto y otros como endpoints para hacer un get y obtener los datos.

Yo me aproximé a esta solución, pero el return me devuelve un array con Promesas pendientes.

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const rootApi = "https://swapi.co/api";

const main = async () => {
  const people = [];
  var next = `${rootApi}/people`;
  do {
    const axiosRequest = await axios.get(next);
    const dataPeople = axiosRequest.data.results;
    people.push(dataPeople);
    next = axiosRequest.data.next;
    console.log(next);
  } while (next !== null);

  const peopleFlat = [].concat(...people);
  const resultado = peopleFlat.map(async p => {
    let promisesArrFilms = p.films.map(film => axios.get(film));
    const obj = {};
    obj.name = p.name;
    obj.height = p.height;
    obj.mass = p.mass;
    obj.hair_color = p.hair_color;
    obj.skin_color = p.skin_color;
    obj.eye_color = p.eye_color;
    obj.birth_year = p.birth_year;
    obj.gender = p.gender;
    obj.films = await Promise.all(promisesArrFilms);
    return obj;
  });

  console.log(resultado);
};

main();
```

Ya sé que habría que limpiar los resultados que me devuelve axios para los films, pero no estoy llegando a la primera instancia que es dejar todos los datos así crudos.

Desde ya agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar otro `Promise.all()` si las  promesas retornan promesas:

`Promise.all(resultado).then(res=>console.log(res));`

```js
//const axios = require("axios");
const rootApi = "https://swapi.dev/api";

const main = async () => {
  const people = [];
  var next = `${rootApi}/people`;
  do {
    const axiosRequest = await axios.get(next);
    const dataPeople = axiosRequest.data.results;
    people.push(dataPeople);
    next = axiosRequest.data.next;
    console.log("va a tardar..");
  } while (next !== null);

  const peopleFlat = [].concat(...people);
  const resultado = peopleFlat.map(async p => {
    let promisesArrFilms = p.films.map(film => axios.get(film));
    const obj = {};
    obj.name = p.name;
    obj.height = p.height;
    obj.mass = p.mass;
    obj.hair_color = p.hair_color;
    obj.skin_color = p.skin_color;
    obj.eye_color = p.eye_color;
    obj.birth_year = p.birth_year;
    obj.gender = p.gender;
    obj.films = await Promise.all(promisesArrFilms);
    return obj;
  });

Promise.all(resultado).then(res=>console.log(res));
 
};

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Te agreadezco mucho tu respuesta, ahí probé y efectivamente me deja el resultado ok. Lo que no me queda claro, y como proceso de aprendizaje me gustaría entender es por qué razón es que retorna el array de promesas, en lugar de devolver el valor. Incluso me llama la atención que por ser una función async, si internamente devuelvo valores sin await, por ejemplo todo menos el obj.films de mi ejemplo, me lo devuelve wrapeado en una promise. Si tenés algún lado donde puda leer un poco más para entenderlo me ayudaría!

Comment: No es raro que una promesa retorne una promesa, incluso podría seguir devolviendo promesas. No hay muchas formas de resolver una promesa, then(), async await, resolve() y resolve all(), no sé si me olvidó de alguna. En este caso habría que hacer console y ver. Es probable que dataPeople, osea el request de axios, sea ya una promesa que se puede hacer await para resolver y evitar hacer el Promise.all. En realidad lo de las promesas no es mucho más que esto, el tema sería como funciona exactamente, en este caso axios y la api.